# How to search for nearby (getting coordinates from browser automatically) with Google Places Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am developing a website and I need a textbox prefilled with the nearest city from Google Places. I am currently using autocomplete to search for nearby, which does ask for browser's location permission, but how do I search for nearby cities using the API itself, without bothering to get user's location from browser and passing it into the Google Places API call? As Google already gets my location from browser anyway, shouldn't it (logically) just search for nearby places in respect to my current location in `nearbySearch`, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

I've ended up getting location from the browser natively and then passing the location to Places API, as Places API apparently doesn't have such (very basic) functionality. Here is how I got the location:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        //service is a PlacesService instance.
        var req = {
            location: pos,
            radius: '50000',
            types: ['(cities)']
        };

        service.nearbySearch(req, function (results, status) {
           ...
        });
}
```